# How to reduce space at bottom of page in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, typography

My word document leaves a lot of blank space on the bottom of some pages for no apparent reason. I even have orphan/widow control turned off so that it will fill the last line even if that leads to an orphan or a widow.

Here's a particularly egregious example:

[image]

The margins should be set to allow for enough room, as you can see here:

[image]

As I said, widow/orphan control is turned off, so that can't be the reason this is happening. There are no footnotes on this or the surrounding pages either. On most other pages, it doesn't do this. But on some it does. Sometimes, as I edit the bottom line, Word does decide to make use of the remaining space. But not always.

How do I always fill that remaining space with text? I'm on Microsoft Word for Mac version 16.46.

Comment: See Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page `Improving the Bottom Line`: http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/BottomLine.htm

Comment: I really like the reference @CharlesKenyon provided.  I myself have had to do A LOT of API documentation using MS Word.   Being really good at this is more of an art than a science.  When I need to add one more line of API information to a doc, sometimes.. I need to go through and reformat the end of every page.. it is just the way it is.  Some flow naturally.. some require me to manually provide page breaks.. some require me to bump down the font in a particular section or change margins.  There is no single answer to your question.

Comment: I read the article, thanks. Looks like I have some manual work cut out for me. Although I wonder how the professionals do it. I checked a few books I own and the bottom lines of each page line up perfectly without exception. Surely there are tools to help with that?

Comment: @weltschmerz Why do you think your books have been created in Word? I would expect that professionals use DTP programs and not Word.

Comment: Word is not a typesetting or page layout program. It is a word processor. The advice in that article can get you even bottom lines, but it does not come naturally with Word, unless: You have fixed line space with no variation and no images or space the images to be a given number of lines. Then you have to eliminate the paragraph formatting of keep with next and keep lines together and widow and orphan control.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Many pages in my document don't have images or any variation and those are my settings and Word still doesn't have even page bottoms. :) @ Robert I don't. Hence my comment "surely there are tools to help with that". But *I'm* pretty much stuck with Word, or at the very least I can't use InDesign – I know that much.

Comment: By the way, my best guess so far for why Word puts all that extra space is this: if it didn't, it would lead to even more extra space on more pages, so this is a kind of optimization that doesn't always result in no extra space – the space we do see is better than all the ones we don't see. But who knows.